# How to set the font weight in the font-family property?

Tags: css

I have the below css code

```
.mybutton{
font-family : Segoe UI Semibold;
}
```

Semi bold applies properly in the above case

I need to change as below

```
.mybutton{
font-family: Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Arial Semibold
}
```

But Semi bold does not applied, how to achieve this with out using font-weight property

Comment: `font: bold 15px "Segoe UI", Helvetica Neue, Arial;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shorthand for font

```
body {
 font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-
 family;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `font-weight` in `font-family` property, You can set it to `font:` property,

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family|caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit;
```

In you project,

`.mybutton{
font: bold  Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Arial Semibold;
}`

Answer (score 0):

For font property font-size and font-family is required, can add other property to it, if did not give font-size and font-family the default values will be inherit

If you dont want to add font-weight:bold then use bold font family

```
.mybutton{
    font: bold 15px Segoe UI, Helvetica Neue, Arial;
}
```